# How to write a Google Apps Script function to find and format a specific character throughout a doc?

Tags: google-apps-script, formatting, google-docs

I'm using docs to save ASCII drawings for a project, and to make it more readable I need the `%` character to always be **gray**. However, manually formatting each `%` would take forever. I suspect I'll need to use a regular expression to locate all of the `%`, but as an amateur programmer I'm not sure how to write the actual function.

In short, the function needs to:

1. Find all `%` characters.
2. Change text color to gray (#cccccc).

The function only needs to be executed once (not constantly in the background).

Thank you for your help!

I've checked the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs, but I wasn't able to figure out how to find and format specific text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a simple example of how to color the %.  This runs from a new menu item and can be run any time.

```
function onOpen() {
  let ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  let menu = ui.createMenu("My Menu");
  menu.addItem("Change %","changeColor");
  menu.addToUi();
}

function changeColor() {
  try {
    let doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    let body = doc.getBody();
    let range = body.findText("%");
    while( range ) {
      let text = range.getElement().asText();
      if( range.isPartial() ) {
        let start = range.getStartOffset();
        let end = range.getEndOffsetInclusive();
        text.setForegroundColor(start,end,"#cccccc");
      }
      else {
        text.setForegroundColor("#cccccc");
      }
      range = body.findText("%",range);
    }
  }
  catch(err){
    console.log("Error in changeColor: "+err);
  }
}
```

References:

- [onOpen() simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)
- [DocumentApp.getUi()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#getUi())
- [DocumentApp.getBody()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body)
- [Body.findText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findText(String,RangeElement))
- [RangeElement.getElement()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range-element#getElement())
- [Element.asText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element#asText())
- [Text.setForegroundColor()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setForegroundColor(Integer,Integer,String))

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to edit the onOpen menu function for the menu to appear, but everything else worked perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me (I only changed the onOpen menu function):

```
function onOpen() {
  let ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Automations')
      .addItem('Format %', 'changeColor')
      .addToUi();
}

function changeColor() {
  try {
    let doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    let body = doc.getBody();
    let range = body.findText("%");
    while ( range ) {
      let text = range.getElement().asText();
      if( range.isPartial() ) {
        let start = range.getStartOffset();
        let end = range.getEndOffsetInclusive();
        text.setForegroundColor(start,end,"#cccccc");
      }
      else {
        text.setForegroundColor("#cccccc");
      }
      range = body.findText("%",range);
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("error in changeColor: "+err);
  }
}
```